# awk to calculate number of days between two dates:

Tags: awk

Would like to calculate number of days between two dates , for the below example,   No of days == $6-$4 position.

Input.txt

```
Desc1,Desc2,Desc3,DATE_ACTIVE,STATEMENT_DATE,Desc4
abc,def,ghi,21-MAR-08,01-JUL-14,jkl
abc,def,ghi,01-JUL-14,15-JUL-14,jkl
abc,def,ghi,06-NOV-06,08-JUL-14,jkl
abc,def,ghi,18-NOV-03,08-JUL-14,jkl
abc,def,ghi,14-JUN-06,15-JUL-14,jkl
```

Desired Output:

```
Desc1,Desc2,Desc3,DATE_ACTIVE,STATEMENT_DATE,Desc4,No_Of_Days
abc,def,ghi,21-MAR-08,01-JUL-14,jkl,2293
abc,def,ghi,01-JUL-14,15-JUL-14,jkl,14
abc,def,ghi,06-NOV-06,08-JUL-14,jkl,2801
abc,def,ghi,18-NOV-03,08-JUL-14,jkl,3885
abc,def,ghi,14-JUN-06,15-JUL-14,jkl,2953
```

Have tried below commands and partial ...

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {print $0,$6-$4}' Input.txt

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {print $0,$date($6)-$date($4)}' Input.txt
```

Any suggestions ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one way to do that:

```
 kent$  awk -F, -v q='"' '{
 c="date -d"q$4q" +%s";c|getline d1;close(c); 
 c="date -d"q$5q" +%s";c|getline d2;close(c);
 printf "%s,%d\n", $0,(d2-d1)/3600/24}' file
abc,def,ghi,21-MAR-08,01-JUL-14,jkl,2292
abc,def,ghi,01-JUL-14,15-JUL-14,jkl,14
abc,def,ghi,06-NOV-06,08-JUL-14,jkl,2800
abc,def,ghi,18-NOV-03,08-JUL-14,jkl,3884
abc,def,ghi,14-JUN-06,15-JUL-14,jkl,2953
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the `awk`, but true date/days calculation:

```
#!/bin/bash
read line < input;
echo -n $line; echo "No_Of_Days";
sed '1d' input| 
while IFS=,
read a b c d e f;
do 
 let DIFF=(`date +%s -d $d`-`date +%s -d $e`)/86400;
 echo -n $a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f,
 echo $(($DIFF *-1));
done
```

produces:

```
Desc1,Desc2,Desc3,DATE_ACTIVE,STATEMENT_DATE,Desc4No_Of_Days
abc,def,ghi,21-MAR-08,01-JUL-14,jkl,2293
abc,def,ghi,01-JUL-14,15-JUL-14,jkl,14
abc,def,ghi,06-NOV-06,08-JUL-14,jkl,2801
abc,def,ghi,18-NOV-03,08-JUL-14,jkl,3885
abc,def,ghi,14-JUN-06,15-JUL-14,jkl,2953
```

Answer (score 0):

The other examples here are script examples in unix, and not necessarily awk. It can be done natively in some awk extensions, such as nawk or gawk, as well, using the `mktime(datespec)` function. You need to convert your date to a standardized format:

```
function getDate(date) {
    split(date, a, "-");
    return mktime("20" a[3] " " sprintf("%02i",(index("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC", a[2])+2)/3) " " a[1] " 00 00 00")
}

BEGIN {FS=","}

{printf("%i\n",0.4+(getDate($5)-getDate($4))/86400)}
```

The extra 0.4 is needed to compensate for leap time units.