# Using AWK to find missing dates in a log

Tags: awk

I am trying to find missing dates in a log file. Essentially, I have 2 input files, an 'eventlist' and an 'eventlog' that look like this:

```
eventlist
EV01 Event number one
EV02 Event number two

eventlog
2014-09-14 EV01
2014-09-16 EV01
2014-09-20 EV01
2014-09-21 EV01
2014-09-22 EV01
2014-09-23 EV01
2014-09-24 EV01
2014-09-25 EV01
2014-09-14 EV02
2014-09-22 EV02
2014-09-23 EV02
2014-09-24 EV02
2014-09-25 EV02
```

I am trying to see the number of consecutive days (from today) that I have eventlog records for. Based on the file above, I would like the output below:

```
6 Event number one
4 Event number two
```

So far I have the script below, but it returns me a count of occurrences for each event:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=$0; next }{print $1,a[$2]}' eventlist eventlog | awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $3))}' | awk -F, '!z[$1]++{ a[$1]=$0; } END {for (i in a) print z[i], a[i]}'
```

This currently returns:

```
8 Event number one
5 Event number two
```

Any ideas on how I can modify the above to show me the number of sequential days (up to today) instead of a total count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love challenges like this. It's late here: explanations upon request tomorrow.

```
gawk '
    BEGIN { today = strftime("%F", systime()) }
    function day_before(date) {
        gsub(/-/, " ", date)
        return strftime("%F", mktime(date " 12 00 00") - 86400)
    }
    NR == FNR  { id = $1; $1 = ""; event[id] = $0; next }
    $NF != eid { day = today; eid = $NF }
    $1 > today { next }
    $1 == day  { count[eid]++; day = day_before(day) }
    END { for (id in count) print count[id], event[id] }
' eventlist <(tac eventlog)
```

```
6  Event number one
4  Event number two
```

Comment: Hi Glenn - Thanks for the answer. This works great. Would you mind walking through this so I can follow? I've accepted the solution, just want to make sure I understand how it works.

Comment: I wouldn't mind, but first are there any **specific** parts you don't understand?

Comment: specifically the 2 lines after the function:     NR == FNR  { id = $1; $1 = ""; event[id] = $0; next }
    $NF != eid { day = today; eid = $NF }

Comment: `NR==FNR` uses 2 awk variables: `NR` == the number of the current record, `FNR`, the number of the current record for the current file. Only for the first file can `NR==FNR`. This action reads the eventlist, storing the events in the `event` associative array.

Comment: `NF` is the number of fields in the current record. `$` is a operator that returns the *value* of a field. $1 is the value of the first field, $NF is the value of the last field. `eid` is a user-defined awk variable. Undefined variables act like the empty string or the number 0 (depending on the context). This action kicks in when the last field **changes** from the previous record.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, suggested by an answer to [Awk to calculate number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135600/awk-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates?rq=1), would be (assuming for simplicity that there is a tab between `EV01` and `Event number one` in the `eventlist` file):

```
#!/bin/sh
cut -f2 -d" " eventlog >ev.tmp
cut -f1 -d" " eventlog | date -f - +%s | awk '{print int($0/86400)}' \
    | paste - ev.tmp | awk '{if (lastDay[$2] == $1-1) consecCount[$2]++; 
else consecCount[$2]=1; lastDay[$2] = $1} 
    END {for (i in consecCount) print i "\t" consecCount[i]}' \
        | sort | join -t"   " - eventlist | cut -f2,3
```

The key step here is that `date -f` converts a file full of dates into seconds since the epoch, so we can divide that number by the number of seconds in a day (86400) to find the number of days since the epoch. Finding the most recent number of consecutive days for each event is then straightforward and we can match the longer labels to each event count with a combination of `join` (using a tab as the field delimiter) and `cut`.

This solution uses more tools than @glenn jackman's solution but avoids the need for `mktime()` and `strftime()`, which may not be available in all dialects of `awk`.

Comment: Simon, I've tried this and the 'join' part does not seem to work. I get an error thrown that says "join: multi-character tab '     '". I tried modifying the spacing next to 'join -t' and the script runs, but I don't see any output?

Comment: @armohan: It is tricky to persuade `join` to use a tab as a delimiter but pressing the <tab> key between double quotes worked for me. Alternatively, you can use the keystrokes <ctrl-v><tab> or you can use other techniques shown in answers to the question [Unix join separator char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722353/unix-join-separator-char).